# How to copy a specific div "a.html" to a "b.html" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put a navbar on all of the pages, but everytime I update my navbar, I have to update it on all pages. So I want to have the navbar in a distinct html file and import it to all pages. By this way I will update the navbar from this distinct file and it will automaticly update itself on all pages. Is there a method for this using jquery?

```
<div id="IAmFromAHtml">Navbar<div> <div id="IAmFromBHtml">Empty Space<div> <div id="IAmFromCHtml">Empty Space<div>
```

For example, I want to copy this navbar text from a.html to b.html and c.html.

Comment: Create a fiddle with your code for more clarity

Comment: You can have a single navbar in an include page and include that everywhere like masterpage or template.

Comment: But I want to have other common divs like common footer etc. in the same html with the navbar. I want to have all the common divs in one html file.

Comment: Only recent versions of Chrome and Opera support doing this natively. You would need to use some sort of UI framework or just inject the navbar with javascript.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this from the client, do it at the server so the full page is delivered from the start and avoid multiple requests for a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery `.load()` docs have an example right at the top that is pretty much exactly what you're attempting: http://api.jquery.com/load/

`$( "#footer" ).load( "footer.html" );`

As for putting all the common elements in **one** file, you'd just have to parse the results in a callback. It might be easier to keep them in separate files.